# How to find .properties file in maven based java web application?

Tags: java, maven, properties

Recently I have developed Java based web application and used maven for making a build.
As per standard convention, I have added all the .properties file in folder "src/main/resources". After deployment of .war in tomcat, I wanted to edit properties file without making new build. Is it possible to edit the properties ? If Yes, In which folder I can find the properties file ?  (I could not find the properties file in the server /tomcat folders)

Comment: are you using spring? Also If this is part of the package then I am not sure you can change the files without unpacking war.

Comment: No, I'm using basic servlet to develop  web app. I have unpacked the war file, Still could not find .class files and Properties files.

Comment: are you able to run this properly? As in is your application running?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web application, inside the war,you should be able to find the contents of src/main/resources in below location:

war -> WEB-INF -> classes folder.

You can edit the properties file there, restart and it should work.

Comment: I tried to find it in the classes folder it is empty, Do we need to specify anything while making build in the maven to get the file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just got to the folder where your war is located somewhere in your system.

```
Target > War > Web-Inf > Classes.
```

Make changes and redeploy.